# Как складывать все содержимое одного int?

Tags: java, android

Есть корзина магазина где надо получить итоговую стоимость.Есть метод

```
holder.textmany.setText(model.getTovarValue());
    holder.textname.setHint(model.getTovarcartShopuid());
    holder.textname.setText(model.getTovarname());
    holder.textplus.setHint(model.getProductId());
    holder.textminus.setHint(model.getPrice());
    holder.textprice.setText(model.getPrice()+"₽");
    int oneTypeProductPrice=(Integer.valueOf(model.getPrice())*Integer.valueOf(model.getTovarValue()));
```

этот инт хранит в себе итоговые стоимости каждого товара по отдельности.Как можно их сложить между собой?

Answer (score 0):

Создайте для каждого объекта .getPrice
К примеру:

```
`for(int i = 0; i < model.length; i++){
int allPrice += model[i].getPrice();
}`
```

Мы прошлись по всем элементам массива, вызвали их стоимость и добавили к общей цене.